# Chaning the image according to what button is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this interface and I want the middle image to change according to which button is clicked. What would I need in order to do this?

http://i62.tinypic.com/kbx9z.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a list of images. Then you can assign a button's `Tag` property to index of an image. Then assign each button's click event to a sinle event such as

private void buttonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.pictureBox1.Image = this.imageList[(int)((Button)sender).Tag];
}